# How to use CASE in SELECT and WHERE clause to Eliminate divide by zero issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008 R2, I have a query which is now giving me a divide by zero error. This is because of a DB column value which was always supposed to be > 0. This has been changed. The column is `wf.reminderFrequency` and is now set to no nulls with a default value of 0.

Here is the query :

```
SELECT 
    wfi.WebFormsInstanceID AS instanceID, 
    wfi.FormActionDate as fLastActionDate, 
    wf.reminderFrequency as fReminderFeq, 
    DATEDIFF(day, CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE),
    CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS theDateDiffCalc,
    DATEDIFF(day, CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE),
    CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) % wf.reminderFrequency AS theModCalc 
FROM 
    (webFormsInstances as wfi 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    WebFormsIndex as wf ON wfi.WebFormsIndexID = wf.WebFormsIndexID) 
WHERE 
    (wfi.formStage <> 'Complete' 
     AND wfi.FormStage <> 'Terminated' 
     AND wfi.FormStage <> 'Payroll Processing') 
    AND (wfi.FormActionDate > 20150101) 
    AND (DATEDIFF(day, CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) % wf.reminderFrequency = 0) 
ORDER BY 
    wfi.WebFormsInstanceID DESC;
```

The query is designed to get all the WebFormsIndex records where no action (difference between today and fLastActionDate) has happened in X (wf.reminderFrequency) number of days.  Please note - The query is more confusing than it needs to be because fLastActionDate is an YYYYMMDD integer value which unfortunately can not be changed.  So how do I change this to handle the scenario where wf.reminderFrequency can now be 0. As you can see this value is being used in a two divisions n the query.

This is my solution for the SELECT part which I think is going to work:

```
SELECT 
    wfi.WebFormsInstanceID AS instanceID, 
    wfi.WebFormsIndexID as fID, 
    wf.FormName as fName, 
    wfi.FormOwner as fOwner, 
    wfi.FormStage as fStage, 
    wfi.FormAction as fAction, 
    wfi.FormActionDate as fLastActionDate, 
    wf.reminderFrequency, 
    wfi.Comments as fComments, 
    DATEDIFF(day, CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE),
    CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) AS theDateDiffCalc,
    CASE
       WHEN wf.reminderFrequency > 0 
         THEN
           DATEDIFF(day, CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) % wf.reminderFrequency 
         ELSE
            '-1'
    END AS theModCalc
FROM 
    (webFormsInstances as wfi
```

But I am having no luck figuring out how to handle the division in the `WHERE` clause.

This does not work:

```
WHERE 
    (wfi.formStage <> 'Complete' 
     AND wfi.FormStage <> 'Terminated' 
     AND wfi.FormStage <> 'Payroll Processing') 
    AND (wfi.FormActionDate > 20150101) 
    CASE
       WHEN wf.reminderFrequency > 0 
         THEN
               AND (DATEDIFF(day, CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE), CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) % wf.reminderFrequency = 0) 
        END AS          
ORDER BY 
    wfi.WebFormsInstanceID DESC;
```

**UPDATE** - Sample data from the first statement:

```
  instanceID  fLastActionDate  fReminderReq  theDateDiffCalc  theModCalc
  24965         20150312          14             14              0
  24965         20150312          14             14              0
  24940         20150226          14             28              0
```

Thanks to @Gordon using nullif was the solution.  Seems to work very well.  It was used like so in the select:

```
 DATEDIFF(day, CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) % nullif(wf.reminderFrequency,0) AS theModCalc
```

and like so in the WHERE:

```
AND (DATEDIFF(day, CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE),CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) % nullif(wf.reminderFrequency,0) = 0)
```

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected result.

Comment: In your last sample, there's a syntax error - the line immediately after the WHEN shouldn't begin with AND - did you make a copying error?

Comment: What do you want to happen if the value is 0?

Comment: @Cindy this is the bit that I can get working.  yes it does look like an out of place AND

Comment: @jc  If its zero it should be omitted form the results.  If the reminder is 0 the business has not set the reminder value which is a number of days

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can handle `NULL` as the value instead of `-1`, I would recommend `NULLIF()`:

```
DATEDIFF(day,
         CAST(CAST(wfi.formActionDate AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE),
         CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)
        ) % nullif(wf.reminderFrequency, 0) AS theModCalc
```

This will work in both the `select` and the `where`.

Comment: Very nice @Gordon.  You the man!   This nullif seems to works very well in both situations as you say.   I have never seen nor heard of this.  A very good day to you...

Comment: @Mat41 . . . Only fairly recently did I learn that `nullif()` is ANSI standard.  That makes it the preferred method for avoiding divide by zero, regardless of the database (although not all databases necessarily support it, the major ones do).